# Two way communication in Catel MessageMediator

Tags: catel

What is the recommended way to set up two way communication through the messagemediator?

My instinct was to create 2 channels (request/reply).  I don't see any way to create channels within the MessageMediator.

Then my idea was to have 2 instances of the messageMeditor but this seems clumsy.

Last I could have a callback as part of my message.  Is this the recommended way to achieve this?

Comment: I am not sure if the MessageMediator is the best way to use a full two-way communication channel. It's possible to add the sender to the messages so you can "Reply" to messages.

If you want this implemented, please create a ticket at http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker

Comment: The problem is the Message mediator has problems with sending messages from inside the handler of the recipient of a message.  I can't remember the exact error but its something do with modifying the collection during enumeration (which I think means that while the Message Mediator is iterating over the collection of message subscribers, you can't add another message).

Comment: What I want to do is have a module send out a request for parameters, I don't know at the time who will provide them (context specific) and have the subscriber to the message fill in the requested data and send it back.  With two channels this would be simple, but I think the easiest way to do it with the existing MessageMediator infrastructure is to have a callback embedded in the message.  I'm going to try that today, but I was curious if maybe there was an existing facility for this use case that I'm not aware of.

Comment: We fixed that issue in the upcoming 4.0 release. We can do a callback, but easiest is the Sender with a Reply extension method.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Sender with a Reply extension method".  Is there an example of this approach anywhere to your knowledge?

Comment: No, it was meant as a future feature description. This is not yet possible.